# removing the first digit of a string for the first n rows in a column

Tags: r

I have a long column with about 5000 rows and each row has 6 digits. I would like to remove the first digit of the first 150 rows. How do I do that?

I tried this function:

```
gsub("^[0-9]","", f1992$cleaned1992)
```

`f1992` is the dataframe and `cleaned1992` is the column that I am working with. The problem is the code removes the first digit for all the 5000 rows.

[Screenshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3NOZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just index to the first 150 rows

```
 gsub("^[0-9]","", f1992$cleaned1992[1:150])
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sub` you can do

```
f1992$cleaned1992[1:150] <- sub(".", "", f1992$cleaned1992[1:150])
```

Or using `substring`

```
f1992$cleaned1992[1:150] <- substring(f1992$cleaned1992[1:150], 2)
```